# Passing more QiChat variables to a Python function

Tags: python, nao-robot

I'm experiencing some issues with the naoqi sdk with Choreographe. I need to pass **synchronously** two or more variables by means of QiChat module to a Python function:

```
u:(Is someone in _~lab lab working on _~themes) $lab=$1 $themes=$2
```

or better:

```
u:(Is someone in _* lab working on _*) $lab=$1 $themes=$2
```

I have not found anything online, can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QiChat raises ALMemory events when a variable is set, but **processing ALMemory events is asynchronous**, therefore you cannot rely on them in your case.

However, QiChat provides a way to make **synchronous calls** to any API exposed in NAOqi, using the [^call keyword](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/naoqi/interaction/dialog/dialog-syntax_full.html). You can take advantage of this to call a method you would have exposed in [a Python service](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/dev/libqi/guide/py-service.html?highlight=python%20service) you would have written yourself. In QiChat you would have something like that:

```
u:(_$myConcept): alright ^call(MyService.myMethod($1))
```

I suppose you write your program using Choregraphe, so please note that you already have access to a valid Qi Session in every Python box, by calling `self.session()`.

Comment: Can I call an ALModule method instead using Python service?

Comment: I try with `^call(self.session().method($1))` but it doesn't work.

Comment: The right way is to write `^call(MyService.myMethod($1))`. I have updated my answer to make this clear.